# Is using static functions in c# a form of functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming

I am a C# developer and have been having trouble getting my head around how to think "functionally" as opposed to "imperatively".

Functional is usually defined  as stateless, where you describe what needs to be done as opposed to how to do it and it occurred to me that the way I like to code having lots of static, stateless functions must be a form of functional programming.

The bottom line even in functional programming where one describes what needs to be done is not done by magic, what needs to be done must be coded somewhere, that is essentially the way i view my static functions.

Am I thinking functionally by coding this way?

Comment: You need to be thinking in terms of _no side-effects_. State is just one form of side-effect. Functional programming also requires a return value, whereas static methods do not.

Answer (score 1):

There are languages like C# and Java that don't allow standalone functions, meaning that every function has to belong to a class.

Now in functional programming you want referential transparency and no side effects. This means that you don't want to access object state. Therefore it makes no sense to make the function non-static.

The best thing you can do to emulate standalone functions it to use static functions. Still you need to make sure the function does not access mutable static class attributes.